# How do I create a new line after hitting another word after a symbol/number using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I have a long text document (over 8000 lines) that I want to enter into excel/google sheets. Issue is that all the text is together separated by a space. I want a 4 column wide by however long it is. I want to sort the words using regular expression because it would be simpler to do in notepad++. So I have something like:

```
Foo-Bar foo2 2 20 50 Bar Foo Foo - - -
```

that I need to sort (names I need to sort). I am looking for a way to do a new line after finding the start of the next word after finding a number/ symbol that is followed by a space. I want the result to look like this:

```
Foo-Bar foo2 2 20 50 
Bar Foo Foo - - -
```

Comment: You say "I want 4 column wide", yet your example contains two rows that are **5** and **6** columns wide, respectively. So how are you determining when to insert a new line? Is it *purely* based on "A number or symbol, followed by a space"? In which case, why was no newline inserted after `foo2`? Because the *next* word *starts with* a letter?

Comment: Perhaps giving a more comprehensive example showing any/all edge cases would be a useful. Can a line contain only 1 word? Will there always be exactly 1 space? Can you have words/numbers like `-2` or `-this`? How should they be treated?

Comment: there is dashes in some of the names, I was thinking about finding everything that had a number followed by a space and a character, or a space followed by a dash and a character. That would filter out all of the words perfectly. Issue is I looked around around and my regex equation is way off. Here was what I have so far: `0[\sA-Z]|\s[\-\sA-Z]`

Comment: I'll answer *this* version of your question below... But to be clear, you've now asked for three different requirements (without complete examples) - so I don't know whether this will actually solve your problem. In future, it is always best to give a full set of requirements up-front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Find everything that had a number followed by a space and a character, or a space followed by a dash and a character.

Using **look-behinds** and **look-aheads**, we can find one or more spaces preceded by a digit and followed by a letter with:

```
(?<=\d)\s+(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

Similarly, we can find one or more spaces followed with a dash then a letter with:

```
\s+(?=-[a-zA-Z])
```

Combining these together is simple:

```
(?<=\d)\s+(?=[a-zA-Z])|\s+(?=-[a-zA-Z])
```

Search for that, and replace all with a new line.